# Firestore operation is hanging

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

Looking for some suggestions to further debug this issue.

I'm writing a Flutter app and have successfully used Firestore for many different operations. However, bizarrely, a very simple operation refuses to  complete. I never get a response from my `await` call:

```
  @override
  Future<void> reportSnap(FeedItem item) async {
    print("Adding report to database: $item");
    await Firestore.instance.collection(_REPORTS).add(
      {
        _ReportsKey.image: item.imageName,
        _ReportsKey.reported: DateTime.now(),
        _ReportsKey.reporter: _user.id,
      },
    );
    print("-> Done"); // Never printed, nothing appears in DB
  }
```

The code that calls this function also never completes:

```
if (wantsToReport) {
  print("Sending report to data service");
  await _dataService.reportSnap(item);
  print("Showing snack message..."); // never shown
  _view.showSnackMessage("Thanks, we'll take a look"); // doesn't happen
}
```

Other database operations continue to work correctly, which seems to rule out hitting any quotas on my free Firebase plan. (I think I'm a *long* way away from those quotas, just desktop testing at the moment).

I appreciate there isn't a lot to go on here, but this is stumping me. Has anyone hit any similar problems before?